# How to map a single char column in Doctrine 2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, annotations, char, mapping

How can I map a single char column in Doctrine 2, using annotations? I would like to have a char type, instead a single char string.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can always use the string type with the fixed option:

```php
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=2, options={"fixed" = true})
 */
protected $country;
```

The above code snippet produces the following SQL:

```sql
`country` char(2) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: I would like to add this note for PostgreSQL, from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html): There is no performance difference among char, varchar and text, apart from increased storage space when using the char(n), and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While char(n) has performance advantages in some other databases, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact char(n) is usually the slowest, because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or varchar should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

You might end up providing your own full-column definition:

```php
/**
 * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="CHAR(2) NOT NULL")
 */
protected $country = null;
```

Comment: You usually don't want to use the columnDefinition property since most likely you are tying yourself to one database engine

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine doesn't have a CHAR type defined out of the box, however it does allow you to define custom types, which you could use to create a 'char' type to use in annotations.

The Doctrine documentation has an example of this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types